# MacPorts dbus session not running

Tags: launchd, macports

2020 MacBook Pro M1 (Apple silicon) I've installed MacPorts dbus with `sudo port install dbus`, and then loaded with `sudo port load dbus` which responds

```
--->  Loading startupitem 'dbus-system' for dbus
--->  Loading startupitem 'dbus-session' for dbus
```

However, `dbus-daemon --session` never seems to run.  What can I do to get it running?